# Put large file to one drive with REST api via c#

Tags: c#, rest, put, onedrive

I want to put a large file (1.4 gb) via [rest api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dn659726.aspx#upload_a_file) to onedrive.

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUri);
webRequest.Timeout = 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
webRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
webRequest.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;
webRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
webRequest.SendChunked = true;
webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
webRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
webRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 1;
webRequest.ContinueTimeout = 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

webRequest.Method = "PUT";
using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.WriteTimeout = 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    writeToStream(stream);
    stream.Flush();
    stream.Close();
}
```

But at arround 200mb I receive an IOException (The underlying connection was closed. Unexpected error during write)

I've searched the internet and found some recommendation to set KeepAlive to false, set the `HttpVersion` and the `ConnectionLimit`, as you can see.

I've tried it with different settings, but it is always the same.

I can not use `HttpClient`, because of Memory consumption.

The code works with small files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneDrive  already  support  large  files  upload   https://gist.github.com/rgregg/37ba8929768a62131e85

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with LIVE SDK for windows runtime.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659730.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh826531.aspx

Hope with this, you can achieve , as it provides asyc upload.

Note: This is off-topic. But still i thought of sharing.I have tried uploading to Amazon S3 using AWS SDK, it does work, and i have tried with around 800MB file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. We tried to use the sdk, but it is not working. We will not use OneDrive anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to upload a file larger than 100MB via the REST API. Hopefully that's a situation that's improved in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The OneDrive Api is totaly crap. We stoped OneDrive support and will only use Dropbox, Google Drive and Box.